# more space appears between spinner and EditTExt

Tags: android

I am writing an android where I need to display Spinner and EditText . I am using LinearLayout with vertical orientation. I am getting lot of space between spinner and EditText.

Comment: There are a few things that could be wrong. You need to supply more information. Such as the layout.xml. My first guess would be that you have margins and/or paddings specified where you do not require them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a resource file to store the set values that the spinner can use?
You can try using "\" character. For example:

```
<string name="test">\This is a test message </string>
```

The "\" character prevents extra blanks from appearing before the first word.